# Lightbox gallery getting concatenated

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, lightbox

I have 3 divs implemented as [lightbox gallery](http://ashleydw.github.io/lightbox/#image-gallery) (3 separate galleries), which are being triggered by clicking on a button. The div is thus set to `display:none` initially.
I've tried to trigger the div via button click by the below method, which is just working correctly. But, all the 3 galleries are getting concatenated i.e in the modal that opens, its showing images of other divs. What could possibly be wrong?

**Script**

```
    $('#button1').on('click', function() {
         $('#div1').show();
    });
    $('#button2').on('click', function() {
         $('#div2').show();
    });
    $('#button3').on('click', function() {
         $('#div3').show();
    });
```

Comment: Can you create a working example, I can't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Used data-gallery="example-gallery" for every box.

```
like div1 boxes images should have  data-gallery="example-gallery1" attribute.
div2 boxes images should have data-gallery="example-gallery2" attribute.
div3 boxes images should have data-gallery="example-gallery3" attribute.
```

Like:

```
data-gallery="example-gallery1" 
data-gallery="example-gallery2"
data-gallery="example-gallery3"

 <a href="https://unsplash.it/1200/768.jpg?image=251" data-toggle="lightbox" data-gallery="example-gallery" class="col-sm-4">
                <img src="https://unsplash.it/600.jpg?image=251" class="img-fluid">
            </a>
```

Comment: Not working, this way, when I press a button that triggers the first div, it does trigger it and shows the gallery. But on pressing the second button, it shows me the same gallery(or div), and not the div it should trigger.